# Dynamic selection of fields from a wide column table

Tags: scala, hadoop, dynamic, hive

I have situation in HIVE where I am picking the required fields from a wide column table ( that has about 250 fields ), joining some other dimension tables to create a snapshot of only required fields with some filter conditions.

However business come and keep asking to add another field or some fields, Currently, I am changing the code every time they ask a new field(s) and it is taking longer time to test and then move it to production. Is there a way that I can dynamically supply the list of fields to be picked up in the SELECT clause? or is there any better approach on how to handle this situation? Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: it depends on how you are running you script.  what you can do is, create a shell script which takes column name as argument and pass it to the hive SQL

Comment: Thanks Gaurang, I am running the hive script as an EMR step function. Also, with shell script argument, i have to pass entire list of select fields as arguments. I'm thinking that I should use some file for the list of fields to be selected and build the SELECT statement on the fly to be submitted to hive.

Comment: putting a fileds in a file is an option. however if not required fields are less, why don't you take that as argument.

Comment: I'm selecting more than 20 fields and sending them as argument in my opinion is not a good solution.

Comment: that's what I am saying, do the reverse, send the column you don't want to select

Comment: I'm not sure how doing the reverse helps. Just to re-iterate my question, I am picking the required fields from a wide column table ( that has about 250 fields )..I need to pick about 30+ fields and don't pick the remaining.